# React .trim() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

My application has a landing page with two components in two separate tabs.

The code from the first component that is causing the crash looks like this:

```
for (let key in linegraphdata) {
  linegraphdata[key].price = Number(
    linegraphdata[key].price.trim().slice(1)
  );
  linegraphdata[key].month = parseDate(linegraphdata[key].month);
}
```

When I load into my application initially it doesn't crash, loads the data from the first tab fine. I'll click into the second tab and when I eventually click back the whole application crashes and the log gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: linegraphdata[key].price.trim is not a function
```

It must have something to do with how React handles refreshing components once already rendered, could anyone help me figure it out please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting what was a `string` to a `number`, and numbers don't have the `trim()` method on them. That's why it works the first time (when it's a string) and not the second time around:

```
array[key] = Number(array[key].trim());
```

So that code must be executing more than once.

Answer (score 2):

`linegraphdata[key].price` is either null or not a string.

If there is a value, you can try using `linegraphdata[key].price.toString().trim().slice(1)`

You can check that price is a string with this ternary. If it's not a string it will set the value to -1

```
linegraphdata[key].price = Number(
    typeof linegraphdata[key].price == 'string' ? linegraphdata[key].price.trim().slice(1) : -1
 );
```

Comment: What if `linegraphdata[key].price` is `null` ? ___Cannot read property 'toString' of null___

Comment: If `price` was `null` the error would be a different one: _"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null"_